# Uniformly partition PySpark Dataframe by count of non-null elements in row

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I know there are a thousand questions out there related to how best to partition your `DataFrames` or `RDD`s by salting keys, etc., but I think this situation is different enough to warrant its own question.

I am building a collaborative filtering recommender engine in PySpark, which means each user (row)'s unique item ratings need to be compared. So, for a `DataFrame` of dimensions `M (rows) x N (columns)`, this means the dataset becomes `M x (K choose 2)` where `K << N` is the number of non-null (i.e., rated) elements for a user.

My algorithm works quite well and efficiently for datasets where users have rated approximately a uniform amount of items. However, for situations where a subset of users have rated a *lot* of items (orders of magnitude greater than other users in the same partition), my data becomes extremely skewed and the last few partitions begin to take large amounts of time. Consider, for a simple example, the following `DataFrame`:

```
cols = ['id', 'Toy Story', 'UP', 'Die Hard', 'MIB', 'The Shining']
ratings = [
    (1, 4.5,  3.5,  None, 1.0,  None),  # user 1
    (2, 2.0,  None, 5.0,  4.0,  3.0),   # user 2
    (3, 3.5,  5.0,  1.0,  None, 1.0),   # user 3
    (4, None, None, 4.5,  3.5,  4.0),   # user 4
    (5, None, None, None, None, 4.5)    # user 5
]

sc.parallelize(ratings, 2).toDF(cols)
```

My situation presents itself in a larger variation of this `DataFrame` (~1,000,000 users and ~10k items) where some users have rated a *much larger* proportion of the movies than others. Initially, I sparsify my `DataFrame` as follows:

```
def _make_ratings(row):
    import numpy as np
    non_null_mask = ~np.isnan(row)
    idcs = np.where(non_null_mask)[0]  # extract the non-null index mask

    # zip the non-null idcs with the corresponding ratings
    rtgs = row[non_null_mask]
    return list(zip(idcs, rtgs))


def as_array(partition):
    import numpy as np
    for row in partition:
        yield _make_ratings(np.asarray(row, dtype=np.float32))


# drop the id column, get the RDD, and make the copy of np.ndarrays
ratings = R.drop('id').rdd\
           .mapPartitions(as_array)\
           .cache()
```

Then, I can examine the number of mutual ratings pairs required for each partition in the following manner:

```
n_choose_2 = (lambda itrbl: (len(itrbl) * (len(itrbl) - 1)) / 2.)
sorted(ratings.map(n_choose_2).glom().map(sum).collect(), reverse=True)
```

Initially, this was the distribution of mutual ratings pairs per partition I got:

[image: First distribution]

As you can see, that's just not scalable. So my first attempt to fix this was to more intelligently partition my data frame at the source. I came up with the following function, which will partition my data frame rows randomly:

```
def shuffle_partition(X, n_partitions, col_name='shuffle'):
    from pyspark.sql.functions import rand
    X2 = X.withColumn(col_name, rand())
    return X2.repartition(n_partitions, col_name).drop(col_name)
```

This worked, kind of. And after applying it, here's the new distribution:

[image: Second dist]

This definitely scales much better, but still not to my liking. There *must* be a way to distribute these "power raters" more uniformly across partitions, but I just can't figure it out. I've been thinking about partitioning by a column of "rating count per user," but that would ultimately lump all of the high-rating-count users together, as opposed to splitting them up.

Am I missing something obvious?

### Update

I implemented **igrinis'** solution in the following function (I'm sure there's a more elegant way to write this, but I'm not super familiar with the `DataFrame` API, so I went back to `RDD` for this—critiques welcome), but the distribution was roughly the same as the original, so not sure if I did something incorrectly or not...:

```
def partition_by_rating_density(X, id_col_name, n_partitions,
                                partition_col_name='partition'):
    """Segment partitions by rating density. Partitions will be more
    evenly distributed based on the number of ratings for each user.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : PySpark DataFrame
        The ratings matrix

    id_col_name : str
        The ID column name

    n_partitions : int
        The number of partitions in the new DataFrame.

    partition_col_name : str
        The name of the partitioning column

    Returns
    -------
    with_partition_key : PySpark DataFrame
        The partitioned DataFrame
    """
    ididx = X.columns.index(id_col_name)

    def count_non_null(row):
        sm = sum(1 if v is not None else 0
                 for i, v in enumerate(row) if i != ididx)
        return row[ididx], sm

    # add the count as the last element and id as the first
    counted = X.rdd.map(count_non_null)\
               .sortBy(lambda r: r[-1], ascending=False)

    # get the count array out, zip it with the index, and then flatMap
    # it out to get the sorted index
    indexed = counted.zipWithIndex()\
                     .map(lambda ti: (ti[0][0], ti[1] % n_partitions))\
                     .toDF([id_col_name, partition_col_name])

    # join back with indexed, which now has the partition column
    counted_indexed = X.join(indexed, on=id_col_name, how='inner')

    # the columns to drop
    return counted_indexed.repartition(n_partitions, partition_col_name)\
        .drop(partition_col_name)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you can do is get a sorted list of users by their number of ratings and then have their index in column divided by the number of partitions. Get the **remainder** of the division as a column, and then repartition with `partitionBy()` on that column. This way you partitions will have almost equal representations of all user ratings count.

For 3 partitions this will get you:

```
[1000, 800, 700, 600, 200, 30, 10, 5] - number of ratings
[   0,   1,   2,   3,   4,  5,  6, 7] - position in sorted index
[   0,   1,   2,   0,   1,  2,  0, 1] - group to partition by
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your answer. I implemented it (in a function I've added in an edit to my question). I think it's a really elegant solution, but for whatever reason I'm not seeing much improvement.

Comment: Welcome. Try to compare histograms of rating distributions for different partitions. If they look similar, than you've reached the bottom. What you still can do is to split "power voter" virtually to several users, and then join the results back, if it applicable. By the way, user's votes supposed to be distributed according to Zipf's law, so having "power voters" is normal.

Comment: The histograms are roughly similar to the shuffled example. That's good to know RE: Zipfian distribution of voters; I did not know that. Even though it has yielded roughly similar results, I think this is the appropriate answer.